# What is the History of Nāgavaṃśa? Is there any mention of them in the Puranas or other texts?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, puranas, history, naga

A lot of jati-s claim descent from the Naga-s, I wanted to know more about their History

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.